# Why is the video in beamer output pdf file playing without sound?

Tags: beamer, multimedia, video

I have a video in my presentation with beamer class. The problem is that in the output pdf file the video is playing without sound. The code is as below:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \movie[width=12cm,height=8cm,poster]{}{a.avi} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally found that the problem was with the video conversion quality. I was converting my video to AVI format which had sound when playing, but in the output pdf file it had no sound. Finally when I converted my video to AVI-Wii, it had sound in the output pdf file.